# In ASP.NET Core Identity, how should I require unique emails only if some user has confirmed the email?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-scaffolding

Out of the box, via identity scaffolding, `UserOptions.RequireUniqueEmail = true` allows an actor to hold any email "hostage", preventing anyone else from ever registering with that email (including the rightful owner). I'm sure there's a workaround, but since this seems to me a significant security hole I'm curious whether a) I'm misunderstanding registration logic or b) there's a common fix apart from setting `UserOptions.RequireUniqueEmail = false`.

Comment: It requires each user to have a unique email, and every email can correspond to an account.

Comment: `how should I require unique emails only if some user has confirmed the email?` Do you mean that you want a duplicate email could be used to register new account if it has been used before but user not confirm the account with that email?

Comment: Security hole, in that confidential email messages could be sent to incorrect user.